# sonarqube mssql packet size

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube

I'm using sonarqube 6.1 with MS SQL Server. I tried running a scan on an app that seems to be generating lots and lots of issues. but at the end of the process, it throws the error below:

```
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 8297ms, dir size=8 MB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 1314ms, zip size=2 MB
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:37.158s
INFO: Final Memory: 50M/481M

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on
http://<server>/api/ce/submit?projectKey=mykey&projectName=pname : 
{"errors":[{"msg":"Fail to insert data of CE task somerandomString"}]}
```

Throughout the Logs, I see some errors parsing some of my css files (which I'm yet to check what's going on) but don;t think that's related. Just mentioning in case it does have something to do with it.

I tried changing my connection string to include Packet Size=65536, but because of the space, not sure if I'm setting it correctly.
I tried

```
sonar.jdbc.url="jdbc:sqlserver:...;Packet Size=65536"
```

that blows up and sonar does not start.
Also Tried

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver:...;"Packet Size=65536" and <BR>
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver:...;Packet Size=65536
```

sonar starts, but same error every time.

First of all, is my error realy related to packet sizes? if yes, what's the right way of changing that for sql server? if not, what else can be going on here?

thanks,

Comment: Have a look at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-db/src/main/java/org/sonar/db/ce/CeTaskInputDao.java). Look also at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/Gs7WbaO4X40) question.

Comment: Your analysis got a 500 status back from the server, so check the server-side logs. BTW, "somerandomeString" is the GUID of the Compute Engine task.

Comment: Yes.. looking at the server logs was the key to find the problem. Thanks. somehow I looked at the client logs and thought that was all I had !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks G. Ann.
The root of my problems were on the server logs!